# Debugging in VSCode Not Working because of ImportError

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, debugging

When I launch VSCode in debug mode, I get an ImportError for `numpy`. However, I have `numpy` installed in my conda environment and was hence wondering why this error message occurs? When I only import Python built-in modules and no third-party libraries, the debug mode runs fine.

Comment: Will it give an error report if you don't use **debug** mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this issue only occurs during the debugging process, you can check your Python interpreter when debugging.

According to [the document](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/debugging):

During debugging, the Status Bar shows the current configuration and the current debugging interpreter. Selecting the configuration brings up a list from which you can choose a different configuration:

[image]

By default, the debugger uses the same interpreter selected for your workspace, just like other features of Python extension for VS Code. To use a different interpreter for debugging specifically, set the value for `python` in `launch.json` for the applicable debugger configuration. Alternately, select the named interpreter on the Status Bar to select a different one.

You can open your `launch.json` and add the following codes according to your conda environment path:

```
"python":"The full path that points to the Python interpreter to be used for debugging."
```